# python removing references from a scientific paper

Tags: python, string

NOTE: I am inexperienced with regular expressions.

I want to be able to convert scientific articles into iTunes tracks. To do this I copy and paste the text in txt files and convert them to spoken tracks. However when I do this the references are included and the computer's voice reads them aloud e.g. "(Smith J. et al. 2016)" and this is annoying as I'd like it to skip anything in brackets containing a reference.
Hence I want to make a python script that removes all of these references from the txt file before converting it to a spoken track.
I reckon that I could do this with something like the following code:

```
start_ref=find("(")
finish_ref=find(")", start_ref)
# then remove all pieces of the string between each start and finish
```

But this is not accurate enough. Instead I would like to somehow use regular expressions.

can someone show me some example code as to how I would iterative remove the references from the following text (while accounting for different referencing styles e.g. Harvard vs APA etc.):

> "This method has been shown to outperform previously discussed methods
>   (Smith, J. et al., 2014) and while it has its draw-backs, it is clear
>   that the benefits outweigh the disadvantages (Jones, A. & Karver, B.,
>   2009, Lubber, H. et al., 2013)."

Can anyone provide some sample code?

Comment: I think you're going to need more than a regular expression to distinguish between a reference and some other parenthetical phrase.

Comment: Echoing @chepner's comment, regexes likely won't be enough. You may want to take a look at natural language processing.

Comment: Catering for only one of the different styles - Harvard *or* APA - in itself is already quite a challenge. Blithely attempting to catch both will only lead to yet even more false matches.

Comment: yes judging by these comments the problem is more complicated than thought. both of the answers below worked for my example string given in the question but when it comes to the actual entire paper neither of the solutions work.... ok thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

something like

```
 import re
 text = ...
 re.sub(r'\((?:[\w \.&]+\, )+[0-9]{4}\)', text)
```

seems to do it.
You can use [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) to train yourself in regex.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
import re

a = "This method has been shown to outperform previously discussed methods (Smith, J. et al., 2014) and while it has its draw-backs, it is clear that the benefits outweigh the disadvantages (Jones, A. & Karver, B., 2009, Lubber, H. et al., 2013)."

a = re.sub(r"\s\([A-Z][a-z]+,\s[A-Z][a-z]?\.[^\)]*,\s\d{4}\)", "", a)
```

It replaces by "" (ie nothing) every string made of a space, `(`, one uppercase letter followed by one or more lowercase letters (ie a name), a comma, a space, one capital letter and a point (optionally separated by a lowercase letter for names like Christine that would be abridged to `Ch.`), then anything but a closing parenthesis until we reach a comma, a space, four digits and a closing parenthesis. To summarize, it assumes that everything that looks like `(Azdfs, E. stuff 2343)` should be deleted. I think that should be enough not to get overdetection.

The output I get with my code is `This method has been shown to outperform previously discussed methods and while it has its draw-backs, it is clear that the benefits outweigh the disadvantages.`