# Remove specific references like author from scientific publication

Tags: python, regex, string

I saw this question before: [python removing references from a scientific paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39936527/python-removing-references-from-a-scientific-paper) It is similar to what I want to do but I still cannot figure out how to do it exactly suppose my string I have a reference like this for example: **Poteete et al. (2010)** How can I remove it from the string using regex in python?

What I have tried is similar with the previous question but maybe I forgot sth:

```
sentence = "Moreover, we elaborate on how these methods have led to improved insights into the theoretical framework proposed by  Poteete et al. (2010)"
sentence = re.sub(r'(?:[\w \.])+[0-9]{4}','',sentence)
```

Any idea for this? Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the name starts with an uppercase char A-Z:

```
[A-Z]\w*(?: +\w+)*\. \(\d{4}\)
```

- `[A-Z]\w*` Match a char A-Z and optional word char
- `(?: +\w+)*` Optionally repeat 1+ spaces and 1+ word chars
- `\.`  Match `.`
- `\(\d{4}\)` Match 4 digits between parenthesis

Instead of matching spaces, you could also use `\s` but that can also match a newline.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jVRE4H/1)

```
import re
 
sentence = "Moreover, we elaborate on how these methods have led to improved insights into the theoretical framework proposed by  Poteete et al. (2010)"
sentence = re.sub(r'[A-Z]\w*(?: +\w+)*\. \(\d{4}\)', '', sentence)
print (sentence)
```

Output

```
Moreover, we elaborate on how these methods have led to improved insights into the theoretical framework proposed by
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, a little question related to this for example if I have a sentence "In  Poteete et al. (2010) , the use of multiple methods in practice has been discussed in detail, resulting in a revised theory of collective action and the commons that includes three elements: individual decision making, microsituational conditions, and features of the broader socialecological context." how to remove it?

Comment: @Erwinwin The pattern matches that same part right? https://regex101.com/r/bX0kRz/1

Comment: If you want to match until the first dot https://regex101.com/r/fhMfue/1

Answer (score 1):

import re

```
s = "Moreover, we elaborate on how these methods have led to improved insights into the theoretical framework proposed by Poteete et al. (2010) and Someone et al. (2010) and something"

print (re.sub(r'[A-Z][a-z]+\set al\.\s\([0-9]{4}\)','',s))
```

Output:

```
Moreover, we elaborate on how these methods have led to improved insights into the theoretical framework proposed by  and  and something
```

Here you detect "et al." followed by a date and preceded by a name with first letter as uppercase". Then you remove it.

Worthless to say those operations are mostly custom, depending on your specific paper, the way the editor formats references, etc. So it must be a pain anyway.